# hg pull/update only if local repository is "clean"

Tags: mercurial

I want to write a script that recursively descends a directory tree, and does an hg pull -u  on all repositories that are "clean" - i.e. have no local diffs, outgoing changesets, or anything else that might make them different to remote. (The script would also do a rebuild, etc.)

Is there a good way to check whether a repository is "clean"? Keep in mind that I would probably be doing this from a bash or python script.

Answer (score 0):

`hg status` is your friend. However, you should be careful about what "clean" means. If all files in your directory structure are under version control, and none of them have changed, `hg status` should return no console output, and (probably) a 0 return code.

If that does not match your definition of clean, you have to be more careful. For example, I commonly do not add generated files (binaries, PDFs from Latex, etc) to version control, but they are inside my directory structure. In that case these files are listed as 'unknown', and I'm sure the return code of hg will differ.

Comment: Does hg status return 0 if there are outgoing changesets? I don't want to do an hg pull -u if the update could result in a merge. I guess I should (separately) check that hg tip matches that of the remote repository?

Comment: `hg status` always returns 0, even when there are local modifications. I guess I could parse the output in python/bash, but this is a bit messy.

Comment: @jhourback - 1. pull **NEVER** merges pulled changesets with local 2. hg st |wc -l returns 0 on clean WC, 3. hg out results  doesn't correlate to pull possibility (read p.1)

Comment: @Jochen - Surely the definition of clean is determined by Mercurial.  If you have files that you don't want to add to version control they should be in the ignore file so that Mercurial then reports the working copy as clean.